# How to link a lot of file .mod .o in GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, gfortran, mingw-w64

i tried to compile without makefile with equations.com gcc
i have bunch of f90, and lib.a
Since a lot of files, i can't use like gfortran *.f90 *.f so i am using gfortran -c filename.f90 each in a batch file.
This create alot of .mod files and .o files.
[code]

```
gfortran -c  -I INCLUDE  -O3 -ffast-math -march=znver3 ALLOCATED_ARRAY_DATA.f90
gfortran -c  -I INCLUDE  -O3 -ffast-math -march=znver3 ALLOCATED_MEMORY.f90
gfortran -c  -I INCLUDE  -O3 -ffast-math -march=znver3 ALLOCATED_MEMORY_Interface.f90
```

[/code]

How to link it to exe with ld with several file?
[code]

```
ld @"names.rsp"
```

[code]

that names.rsp contains
[code]

```
 ../superlu/lib/superlu.a \
 ../superlu/src/c_fortran_dgssv.o \ 
 ../superlu/lib/libopenblas.a \
ALLOCATED_ARRAY_DATA.o \
ALLOCATED_MEMORY.o \
ALLOCATED_MEMORY_Interface.o \
/o mys.exe
```

[/code]

Comment: .mod files just contain compiler information, they are not to be linked.

Answer (score 0):

I think better to study cross-compiling-linking using CMAKE and building using jom or make, than to do it manual.